# Rounding and formatting the nullable decimal in c#

Tags: c#, format, rounding

Im using the below code to round the decimal to 2 decimal places.

```
  decimal? RTime = RTime.HasValue ? Decimal.Round(RTime.Value, 2) : 0;
```

But converting numberlike 512->512.00 is not working..How do i do that?

Comment: "512->512.00 is not working" What does this mean? What do you get as result?

Comment: Do you want to print it as 512.00? If so, take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/format

Comment: Rounding and formatting are different steps. When rounding 512 to 2 decimals it stays 512, however what you want is to **print** a formatted value for 512. Furthermore you can´t declare `RTim` and use its value in the same statement. Maybe you ment something like `decimal? rtime = RTime.HasValue ? Decimal.Round(RTime.Value, 2) : 0;` (notice case of `rtime`). In this case `rtime` does not need to be a `Nullable` but a simple `decimal`.

Comment: Strange question, but you do realise that 512 and 512.00 are the same number right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Decimal.Round` *rounds* the value of the decimal. For example `512.123` to `512.12`.

What you want is a *string representation*. You need to *format* the value instead of *rounding*. You can use `ToString()` for that:

```
decimal? RTime = RTime.HasValue ? Decimal.Round(RTime.Value, 2) : 0;
string RTimeAsString = RTime.Value.ToString("0.00");
```

or `string.Format` or string interpolation like this:

```
string RTimeAsString = string.Format("{0:0.00}", RTime);
string RTimeAsString = $"{RTime:0.00}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing rounding and formatting.

- What you are doing is rounding and it works.
- What you expect is formatting, ie. the way it is displayed on screen. For this you should use the .ToString() method with a corresponding format.